# Why is the graph $K_{3,3} $ not one skeleton of the sphere?

Tags: algebraic-topology

I know that someone has already asked the same question 
[here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/32117/hatcher-s2-having-a-cw-complex-of-5-6-vertices), but there is no solution for part two of the question. And I'm interested in the second part. Here the question:

Suppose we build $S^2$ from a finite collection of polygons by identifying edges in pairs. Show that in the resulting CW complex structure on $S^2$, the 1-skeleton cannot be the graph $K_{3,3}$

I know that the Euler characteristic of the spere $S^2$ is 2. Since the graph has 6 vertices and 9 edges, we have 5 polygons ( since 6-9+x=2 so x=5). So we habe in total 5 polygons with 18 edges (since always two edges are identified). Now I don't know how to find a contradiction. For me it doesn't look so easy. For example I know that the triangular prism has exactly 5 sides, 6 vertices and 9 edges. But obviously the graph is not the one skeleton of this prism.

Comment: K3,3 is not a planar graph and so cannot be embedded in a disc. Since S^2 is formed by gluing two discs along their boundary, it's skeleton can not be K3,3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am assuming that you know that $K_{3,3}$ is not planar.

Recall that a graph is planar if it can be embedded in $D^2$. Now suppose by contradiction that $K_{3,3}$ is a 1-skeleton of $S^2$. Remove a small open disc in the interior of a face the sphere. What is left is a disc which implies $K_{3,3}$ is planar.

**Alternatively:**
(This answer is due to your comment.)
If $K_{3,3}$ is the 1-skeleton of a sphere, use $v-e+f=2$ to show $f=5$.Take a look at graph of $K_{3,3}$. Show that the least number of edges that bound a face is $4$. Since there are $5$ faces, we have atleast $5\times4$ edges. Using the fact that any edge bounds at most two faces, deduce that we have $e\geq10$. Does this agree with value of $e$ you stated with?

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! In the lecture we never talked about planar graphs. We just discussed Euler charakteristic. Why does a graph need to be planar to be a one skeleton of a sphere? How can I prove that the graph is planar? Is there a solution without using more than just Euler characteristic?

Comment: For  a connected planar simple graph with v vertices and e edges, and no triangles, e ≤ 2v - 4. If you can show this, then it is easy to see why K3,3 is not planar.

Comment: Hint: Use euler characteristic of a graph and the handshaking lemma. I'm sure you have these tools.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers. Now I understand it. You helped me a lot!