# CW structure on 2-sphere with $K_5$ and $K_{3,3}$ as 1-skeletons with face edges self-identified

Tags: general-topology, graph-theory, algebraic-topology, cw-complexes

The following is an exercise from Hatcher's *Algebraic Topology*:

> Suppose we build $\mathbb S^2$ from a finite collection of polygons by identifying edges in pairs. Show that in the resulting CW structure on $\mathbb S^2$ the $1$-skeleton cannot be either of the two graphs $K_5$ (the complete graph with $5$ vertices) or $K_{3,3}$ (the complete bipartite graph between sets of $3$ vertices).

This question is answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/32117/1-skeleton-of-s2-cant-be-graphs-k-5-or-bipartite-graph-k-3-3) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/663816/why-is-the-graph-k-3-3-not-one-skeleton-of-the-sphere), but both solutions make a crucial assumption: *we do not identify edges from the same polygon.* So for example, the classic CW structure on the torus with one face (a square), two edges (opposite sides of the square), and one vertex, resulting in the $1$-skeleton $\mathbb S^1 \vee \mathbb S^1$, would not be permitted.

**My question:** Why can't we construct a CW structure on $\mathbb S^2$ with edges of the same face identified, and for which the resulting $1$- skeleton is $K_5$ or $K_{3,3}$?

If $K_5$ is the $1$-skeleton of a weird CW complex on $\mathbb S^2$, then it would have to have $7$ faces by considering the Euler characteristic. There are certain kinds of polygons with self-identified edges that wouldn't be allowed; a triangle with an edge identified, for example, would include self-loops or vertices connected with two edges, which don't exist in $K_5$. But the casework needed to look at each type of self-identification is incredibly tedious, and I'm not sure how I'd do that systematically anyways (especially if we identify vertices and not edges, creating "parachutes" as sub-CW-complexes).

Any thoughts?

Comment: I'd guess it's just "implied" from the phrasing of the question. But Hatcher isn't always the clearest of writers

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez that construction doesn't have $K_5$ as the $1$-skeleton. I know you can have SOME CW structure with self-identified edges

Comment: @FShrike I figured, and I can accept that, but I'm still curious about this variation on the problem haha

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez oh I see. I've edited the question to clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The missing link --- which requires the Jordan-Schonflies Theorem --- is that for every embedded graph $G  \subset S^2$ that is homeomorphic to either $S_5$ or $S_{3,3}$, the graph $G$ is the $1$-skeleton of a CW structure on $S^2$ having the following property:

> **Embedded 2-cells:** The characteristic map $D^2 \mapsto S^2$ of each $2$-cell is an embedding.

It follows that the attaching map $S^1 \mapsto S^2$ of each 2-cell is an embedding, and therefore we clearly do not "identify edges from the same polygon".

I'll prove that the *Embedded 2-cells* property holds for all nonempty, finite, connected graphs $G$ embedded in $S^2$ that satisfy the following hypothesis, which is clearly true for the cases $G=S_5$ and $G=S_{3,3}$:

> **Lots of circles:** $G$ is a finite connected graph For every edge $e \subset G$ there exists an embedded circle in $G$ that contains $e$.

Assuming this hypothesis, to describe the desired CW structure on $S^2$, for any component $K$ of $S^2-G$ it suffices to produce an embedding $D^2 \mapsto S^2$ that takes $S^1 = \partial D^2$ homeomorphically to a circle in $G$ and that takes $\text{interior}(D^2)=D^2-S^1$ homeomorphically onto $K$.

For the proof, we first consider any embedded circle $C \subset G \subset S^2$. By applying the Jordan-Schönflies Theorem we conclude the following:

- $C$ separates $S^2$ into two components,
- the closure of each such component $D$ may be written as $\overline D = D \sqcup C$,
- there exists a homeomorphism $\overline D \approx D^2$ with respect to which $C \approx S^1$.

Let's refer to this conclusion by saying that $\overline D$ is a *disc with boundary $C$ in $G$*.

The set of discs with boundary in $G$ is partially ordered by inclusion.

I'll prove that the 2-cells of the desired CW structure are precisely those discs with boundary in $G$ that are minimal elements of the partial ordering. To prove this, consider any component $K$ of $S^2-G$. For every embedded circle $C \subset G$, clearly $K$ is contained in one of the two discs with boundary $C \subset G$, and so $K$ is contained in some innermost disc with boundary in $G$ that we denote $\overline D_K$. The interior of $\overline D_K$ is disjoint from $G$, for otherwise we could find a smaller disc with boundary in $G$ that contains $K$. It follows that the interior of $\overline D_K$ is equal to $K$, and that the homeomorphism $\overline D_K \approx D^2$ coming from the Jordan-Schönflies theorem satisfies the requirements of a characteristic map for $K$ as an open 2-cell. Doing this for every such $K$, we obtain the collection of characteristic maps needed to define the CW structure.